# How to parse text file with line feeds with Scala to build a CSV file?

Tags: scala, csv

I'm looking for help to parse this text file.  I have this sample part of the file.  It’s like a list of names in a file that I like to turn into a CSV file.   It looks like this:

```
Membership Date:  Jan 1, 1999        
Sponsors:  Mary Muray, Judy White,
                                    Ronald Zurch,
                                   Nina Lin,
                                   Nathan Garton,
                                   Howard Ross  
    Comments:  This are great members to have on our team.
```

Here is the expected output with quotes (“):

```
“Membership Date:  Jan 1, 1999",
"Sponsors:  Mary Muray, Judy White, Ronald Zurch, Nina Foss, Nathan Garton, Howard Ross“,
“Comments:  This are great members to have on our team.”
```

Note that the output has 3 fields. And the sponsor field has the line feeds taken out, so all names are in one field.

My code looks like this:

```
val filename: String = "/data/members.csv"
val lines = Source.fromFile(filename).getLines().toList
val ToLines = lines.dropWhile(line => !line.startsWith("Sponsor: ")).takeWhile(line  => !line.startsWith("Comments: ")).toSeq
```

The last line of code places each name in each element in the sequence, any line is placed into its own separate element in the list. I need help to get all names to be in a single element, so when I save the results as a CSV, the sponsor field has all its names in one field.  Let me know if this does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not have one name in it's own element in the list, it will have each row as an element. You also need to use `split(",")` to separate the names into it's own lelements. After that you can use `mkString(", ")` to merge the list together into a single string. Here is some code that does this and some trimming of white spaces and removal of empty list elements. Note that in the file you have `Sponsors:` while in the `dropWhile` it's `Sponsor:`, these need to be consistent for it to work properly.

```
val sponsors = lines
  .dropWhile(line => !line.startsWith("Sponsors: "))
  .takeWhile(line  => !line.startsWith("Comments: "))
  .flatMap(_.split(","))
  .map(_.trim())
  .filter(_.nonEmpty)
  .mkString(", ")
```

This will give a single string as such:

```
Sponsors:  Mary Muray, Judy White, Ronald Zurch, Nina Lin, Nathan Garton, Howard Ross
```

Adding the date and comments to the sponsors:

```
val data = lines.head.trim()
val comments = lines.last.trim()

val members = List(data, sponsors, comments).map(s => "\"" + s + "\"").mkString(",\n")
```

Will give you a string as follows:

```
"Membership Date:  Jan 1, 1999",
"Sponsors:  Mary Muray, Judy White, Ronald Zurch, Nina Lin, Nathan Garton, Howard Ross",
"Comments:  This are great members to have on our team."
```

Depending on what you want to do with it you can modify the above code for the final result.

Answer (score 1):

I knew this is not an elegant way yet I tried to solve this using typical looping instead of using any built-in functions.This logic can be tweaked according to your actual requirement

```
 val file: BufferedSource = Source.fromFile("file name")
 val lines = file.getLines()
 val result = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]

 val temp = new StringBuilder();

    for (line <- lines) {
      if (temp.mkString.contains(":") && line.contains(":")) {    
        result.append("\"" + temp.toString + "\"")
        temp.clear()
      }
      temp.append(line.trim())
    }

    if (temp.length > 0) result.append("\"" + temp.toString() + "\"")
    temp.clear()

    result.foreach { println(_) }
```

**Output**

```
"Membership Date:  Jan 1, 1999"
"Sponsors:  Mary Muray, Judy White,Ronald Zurch,Nina Lin,Nathan Garton,Howard Ross"
"Comments:  This are great members to have on our team."
```

Comment: I mean this in the nicest possible way (I do this all the time myself), but that is pretty much Java code and not Scala code.

Comment: @Phil yes i agree with you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you might be a little more flexible in identifying what is a new line,and what is a line continuation.

```
io.Source.fromFile("members.csv")
  .getLines
  .foldLeft(List.empty[String]){(all,line) =>
    if (line.contains(": ")) line.trim :: all
    else all.head + " " + line.trim :: all.tail
  }.reverse.mkString("\"", "\",\n\"", "\"")
```

A single call to `mkString()` adds all the requested quote marks and comma separators.